# Why does discord.py discord.ext.commands not work?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, botframework, python-3.9

I tried making a bot with discord.py

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description="This is a test bot")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')



@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")
```

It doesn't send messages when i tell it to. I am using discord.py 1.7.3 with python 3.9.4
The console says it connected but it doesn't do anything other than appear online.
i told it

```
$ping
```

[image: The console says it did connect]

full code:

```py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands

# load token (dont share pls)
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client = discord.Client()

# Is this better?
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description="This is a test bot")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


# commands here

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send('{} arguments: {}'.format(len(args), ', '.join(args)))


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You're running the `client` not `bot`... Why should it work?

Comment: wow thanks really appreciate it it works now

Comment: whats the difference between bot and client though

Comment: `commands.Bot` has *all* the functionality of `discord.Client` in addition to a full command system.

Answer (score 1):

you cant run both `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot`

since `Bot` is the same as `Client`, with some extra functionality, you should use Bot

remove: `client = discord.Client()`
change: `@client.event` to `@bot.event` and `client.run()` to `bot.run()`